# Click handler not working on aframe primitive geomerty objects

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I have added click handler on  primitive geometry from aframe as below :

```html
<a-scene>
  <a-sphere id="ball" cursor-listener material="color: red" position="-3 3 -5" onclick="showplane('#box1')" >
  </a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

I want to animate a plane geometry on click of sphere and when plane is visible to user , I need to attach an click handler for the plane.

JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bhupi1011/9ptLqa32/

Click handlers on not working on either of geometries..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a [cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html#sidebar) to the scene. For mouse click you can do:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
```

Use a component to handle click events:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('select', {
  init: function () {
    var originalColor = this.el.getAttribute('material').color;
    var self = this;
    this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      var color;
      if (evt.detail.intersectedEl === undefined) { return; }
      var color = evt.detail.intersectedEl === self.el ? 'green' : originalColor;
      self.el.setAttribute('color', color);
    }, false);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jungle-plate.glitch.me/

Code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jungle-plate?path=select.js:12:3